# Data Binding not auto generated after upgrading to Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-databinding

After upgrading to new Android Studio 3.1 (i don't remember 3.0.1 happens or not) my Data Binding cannot auto generated variables.

I always have to rebuild project after add more id `@+id/abc` to get `databinding.abc`.

Other example is: in the previous version, I can redirect to layout file by clicking on ViewBinding of its screen. But now I can't.
What do I have to do to get them back?